# How to make the title of the text shift away from the mouse

Tags: java, windows, swing, netbeans, swingx

How to make the title of the text shift away from the mouse, when the mouse is directed to the title of the text in java.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think your question is very vague. What text ? what do you mean by "the title of the text" ?

Comment: Yes. I mean the title of the text

Comment: I tried to make a the titlle of the text .When to hold the mouse in the title of the text then the text is moving away

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mouseExit` and `mouseEntered` `actionListener`'s to do this:

Simple Example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Shift {
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;
    Shift(){
        initComp();
    }

    public void initComp(){
        frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setSize(300,200);

        label = new JLabel("Hello");
        label.setSize(10, 10);
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);

        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
                labelToMiddle(evt);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
                labelToEdge(evt);
            }
        });

        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void labelToEdge(MouseEvent evt) {  
        label.setForeground(Color.RED);
        label.setLocation(0,0);
        label.repaint();
    } 

    private void labelToMiddle(MouseEvent evt) {   
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        label.setLocation(100,0);
        label.repaint();
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shift s = new Shift();
    }
}
```